# Cannot select javascript populated form options in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, forms

I have created a website for an estate agent and there is a search form on the left hand side of the page which is partially populated by javascript depending on whether the viewer wants to rent or buy a home. This works perfectly on desktop browsers but not on a iPad.

When you click on some of the other drop downs the first selection (buying/selling) is highlighted.

The test site is: http://test.southampton-property.com/index.php

The form code is:

```
<p><form method="POST" action="http://test.southampton-property.com/listing.php" name="myform"><label>I'm interested in...</p>
<p><select onChange="changeOptions()" name="de" id="searchType">
<option value="RS">Buying a Home</option>
<option value="RL">Renting a Home</option>
</select>
</label></p>
<p style="margin-top:6px"><label onclick="">Type of Property...<br />
<select name="st">
<option value="ALL">All</option>
<option value="BUNG">Bungalow</option>
<option value="COTT">Cottage</option>
<option value="FLAT" selected="selected">Flat/Apartment</option>
<option value="HOUS">House</option>
<option value="HOUS">Retirement Property</option>
<option value="STUD">Studio</option>
</select>
</label></p>
<p style="margin-top:6px"><label onclick="">Minimum Bedrooms...<br />
<select name="be">
<option value="0">Studio</option>
<option value="1">1 Bedroom</option>
<option value="2">2 Bedrooms</option>
<option value="3">3 Bedrooms</option>
<option value="4">4 Bedrooms</option>
<option value="5">5+ Bedrooms</option>
</select> </label></p>
<p style="margin-top:6px"><label onclick="">Maximum Price...<br /> <select name="pt" id="price"> <option value="75000">&pound;75,000</option> <option value="100000">&pound;100,000</option> <option value="125000">&pound;125,000</option> <option value="150000">&pound;150,000</option> <option value="200000">&pound;200,000</option> <option value="250000" selected="selected">&pound;250,000</option> <option value="300000">&pound;300,000</option> <option value="350000">&pound;350,000</option> <option value="400000">&pound;400,000</option> <option value="450000">&pound;450,000</option> <option value="500000">&pound;500,000</option> <option value="1000000">&pound;1,000,000</option> </select> </label></p>
<p><input name="SUBMIT" class="button" value="Find your ideal Property" type="submit" /></form></p>
```

The javascript that loads the rental/sales figures is:

```
// JavaScript Document
function changeOptions()
{

var index = document.getElementById("searchType").selectedIndex;
var pt=document.getElementById("price");
if(index==1) {
pt.options[0] = new Option('\u00A3400', '400');
pt.options[1] = new Option('\u00A3500', '500');
pt.options[2] = new Option('\u00A3600', '600');
pt.options[3] = new Option('\u00A3700', '700');
pt.options[4] = new Option('\u00A3800', '800');
pt.options[5] = new Option('\u00A3900', '900');
pt.options[6] = new Option('\u00A31000', '1000');
pt.options[7] = new Option('\u00A31100', '1100');
pt.options[8] = new Option('\u00A31200', '1200');
pt.options[9] = new Option('\u00A31300', '1300');
pt.options[10] = new Option('\u00A31400', '1400');
pt.options[11] = new Option('\u00A31500', '1500');
pt.options[12] = new Option('\u00A31600', '1600');
pt.options[13] = new Option('\u00A31700', '1700');
pt.options[14] = new Option('\u00A31800', '1800');
pt.options[15] = new Option('\u00A31900', '1900');
pt.options[16] = new Option('\u00A32000', '2000');
pt.options[17] = new Option('\u00A32100', '2100');
pt.options[18] = new Option('\u00A32200', '2200');
pt.options[19] = new Option('\u00A32300', '2300');
pt.options[20] = new Option('\u00A32400', '2400');
pt.options[21] = new Option('\u00A32500', '2500');
pt.options[22] = new Option('\u00A32600', '2600');
pt.options[23] = new Option('\u00A32700', '2700');
pt.options[24] = new Option('\u00A32800', '2800');
pt.options[25] = new Option('\u00A32900', '2900');
pt.options[26] = new Option('\u00A33000', '3000');

}
else {
pt.options[0] = new Option('\u00A375,000', '75000');
pt.options[1] = new Option('\u00A3100,000', '100000');
pt.options[2] = new Option('\u00A3125,000', '125000');
pt.options[3] = new Option('\u00A3150,000', '150000');
pt.options[4] = new Option('\u00A3200,000', '200000');
pt.options[5] = new Option('\u00A3250,000', '250000');
pt.options[6] = new Option('\u00A3300,000', '300000');
pt.options[7] = new Option('\u00A3350,000', '350000');
pt.options[8] = new Option('\u00A3400,000', '400000');
pt.options[9] = new Option('\u00A3450,000', '450000');
pt.options[10] = new Option('\u00A3500,000', '500000');
pt.options[11] = new Option('\u00A31,000,000', '1000000');
pt.selectedIndex=5;

}
}
```

I'm not really a programmer (just patching bits together) and so do not have a deep understanding of what is going on. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. But can anyone help? I placed the onclick="" as an attempt to fix this problem but this doesn't work.

:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your label tag right before "I'm interested in" that is causing the trouble.

Move it right before the select for the first box.

```
<p><form method="POST" action="http://test.southampton-property.com/listing.php" name="myform">I'm interested in...</p>
<p><label><select onChange="changeOptions()" name="de" id="searchType">
```

Comment: Thanks Lawson – so simple! :-D